# General styling but different nuances depending on the component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, frontend, angular-components

I'm trying to apply some styling to my Angular application and I'd like, for most of the views, to have a certain style. However, I'd like to apply a different style for a bunch of other components.

Is it possible to ask Angular to apply a certain css for some components, and a different style for others by using scss or any other tool that Angular provides and I'm not aware about? Like *ngIf in the app.component.html and retrieve in the .ts the component that is currently being displayed in the `<router-outlet>`? Or it's just not possible

Comment: You have style.css file use this for global css. and you have component.css file for each component, use this file to apply style to only those components only. Thank You.

Comment: I can't. See if I have the code: 
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
I need to change the surrounding of the component (the container), not the component itself

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the desired component selector is: `selector: 'app-message-list'`
You could only target the component with css by:

```css
app-message-list {
width: 80%;
background: red;
}
```

Comment: So that would be in the app.component.scss, right? I've tried that but the content won't change (I also tried selecting it with .container > app-message-list as it's within a container, but no results)